# Float data from AVAudioPCMBuffer is to small even when it clips on audio interface

Tags: avfoundation, core-audio

I couldn’t really find information about this so I decided to ask the question here.

I’m getting the values from the float data. Double-checked in AudioKit and they’re doing the same thing and I’ve got the same issue when I copy/paste their code as well.

```swift
guard let floatData = buffer.floatChannelData else { return }

        let channelCount = Int(buffer.format.channelCount)
        let length = UInt(buffer.frameLength)

        // n is the channel
        for n in 0 ..< channelCount {
            let data = floatData[n]

            if analysisMode == .rms {
                var rms: Float = 0
                vDSP_rmsqv(data, 1, &rms, UInt(length))
                amp[n] = rms
            } else {
                var peak: Float = 0
                var index: vDSP_Length = 0
                vDSP_maxvi(data, 1, &peak, &index, UInt(length))
                amp[n] = peak
            }
        }
```

The issue is that floating values are always so small and doesn’t reflect the correct value. When I increase the gain in my audio interface for it to clip, the values are still below 1,0. Moreover, it’s always too close to zero.

Could anyone suggest how to properly plot it?

## Update

I've noticed that the maximum value is always `0.7071067` when I turn the input gain of my audio interface to max and use `vDSP_maxvi`

```swift
let floatData = buffer.floatChannelData!
let length = UInt(buffer.frameLength)
var peak: Float = 0
var index: vDSP_Length = 0
vDSP_maxvi(floatData[0], 1, &peak, &index, UInt(length))
print(peak)
```